# What is the "Code" radio button for Publishing in Azure App Services for when Creating a Web App?

Tags: azure, azure-appservice

In App Services, when you "Create Web App," there is a place where you publish as Code, Docker Container, & Static Web App.

I can find out everything but what the Code part means.  Since "Code" is so broad, searching was hard to find anything.  I found a bunch about Static Web App (I don't need the container part.)

What is the "Code" option for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Code` is for when you are deploying a web application into the *App Service*, selecting this option will enable the deployments options which will provide an interface so you can choose to enable *Continuous Integration* and subscribe to changes in a GitHub or Azure DevOps repository:

[image: Select Code]

[image: provide subscription details]

Choose `Code` if you have a code project to manage your application, and you are using a compilable web application, especially if it is a SPA application.

Choose Docker if you want to deploy your application as a *Docker* image.

Choose Static Web Pages if your site is a simple HTML/CSS website using traditional html web pages.